# how to find and copy specific column using vba

Tags: excel, vba

Could you please help me i need excel to find column "goods" from sheets1 and copy it into sheet3 and do it the same with sheet2. I need to have the data copied in to one sheet3 in one A column (one after another). but below code while copying just swaping data. and i have only data from sheet2 in my sheet3

```
Sheets("sheet1").Select
desc = WorksheetFunction.Match("goods", Rows("1:1"), 0)
cst = WorksheetFunction.Match("goods", Rows("1:1"), 0)
Sheets("sheet1").Columns(desc).CopyDestination:=Sheets("sheet3").Range("A:A)
Sheets("sheet2").Columns(cst).CopyDestination:=Sheets("sheet3").Range("A:A")
```

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `Range().Find` over `WorksheetFunction.Match`.  Mainly because you don't have to type cast your lookup value with `Range().Find` (e.g. `WorksheetFunction.Match("1234", Rows("1:1"), 0)` does not work.

Here I use it as a convenient way to find the start of the ranges.

[image]

```
Sub CopyGoods()

    Dim goods As Range

    Set goods = Sheets("sheet1").Rows(1).Find("goods")

    If goods Is Nothing Then

        MsgBox "Goods does not exists on Sheet1", vbInformation, "Goods not found"

    Else

        goods.EntireColumn.Copy Sheets("sheet3").Range("A1")

    End If

    Set goods = Sheets("sheet2").Rows(1).Find("goods")

    If goods Is Nothing Then

        MsgBox "Goods does not exists on Sheet2", vbInformation, "Goods not found"

    Else

        Set goods = Range(goods.Offset(1), goods.Offset(Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp))
        goods.Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This article may change your mind: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=find%20vs%20match%20vba

Comment: I'm glad you likes :)

Comment: i tried to add statement else msgbox("goods does not exist") after if not goods is nothing but i had an error.

Comment: You can not append an `EntireColumn` to the end of a list.  `EntireColumn` + 1 is too many rows.

Comment: The parenthesis are causing the error.  If you are using `MsgBox` to return a value; e.g. `response = MsgBox("",vbYesNoCancel) `but if you are not assigning don't use the  parenthesis;  e.g. `MsgBox "Goods does not exists on Sheet1", vbInformation, "Goods not found"` .  Alternately, you can leave the parenthesis and use `Call MsgBox`; `MsgBox("Goods does not exists on Sheet1", vbInformation, "Goods not found")`.